# how to get value of json array object in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you see in the image I have an array of objects. I want to get all keys in an array and values in another array.

[image]

```
function getLatestTableJson(LatestAssetIds) {
    if(LatestAssetIds.length > 0) {
        require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr) {
            xhr("/rest/viewers/latestassetmeasurements/latest", 
                { query: { assetId: LatestAssetIds }, handleAs: "json" }).then(function(response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                alert("I am in process please wait");
                var latestResponseData=response.items;
                console.dir(latestResponseData);
```

in this code response is coming in from of above image. i want to store key and value in arr.

Comment: Have you tried anything? How are you getting this array of objects?

Comment: It seems to be a string with an object definition actually. Check out [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: i think it is parsed or stringify maybe because if not alert will show [Object object]

Comment: sir, I am getting only [object object] but i want to store all key in one array and value in another array.

Comment: I cannot see your picture - please add your code as text to your question.

Comment: function getLatestTableJson(LatestAssetIds)
       {
        if(LatestAssetIds.length > 0)
         {
          require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
          xhr("/rest/viewers/latestassetmeasurements/latest", {
          query: {
          assetId: LatestAssetIds
       },
      handleAs: "json"
      }).then(function(response){
     alert(JSON.stringify(response));
     alert("I am in process please wait");
     var latestResponseData=response.items;
     console.dir(latestResponseData);  in this code response is coming in from of above image. i want to store key and value in arr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope.. It should do the trick

```
var inputString=[{"rKVAH_Lag":"xyz","Asset_Name":"GSM Meter"}];

var keys=[]
var values=[]
i=0
for (var key in inputString[0]) {
    keys[i]=key;
    values[i]=inputString[0][key]    
    i=i+1
}
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you.

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 },
    keys = Object.keys(obj),
    values = keys.map(function (k) { return obj[k]; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(keys, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```